# Visualforce Remoting Exception: Unable to determine from which page the request originated

Tags: javascript-remoting, exception, remote-action

I am using remote calling from my visualforce page, and it is working fine, but for some reason, it is throwing the exception

> Visualforce Remoting Exception: Unable to determine from which page
>   the request originated Object

in another system.

Comment: Can u share little more explanation with Code?

Comment: it is not much of the code, I am calling it and remoting get called, as I put debugs, the last statement at controller side is a return statement, and till that the logs were created.

Comment: Hi @LalitKishor, I am facing the same issue for one of the user on iPadAir device. Have you found any solution or workaround to this issue?

Comment: What do you mean "in another system"?

Answer (score 0):

I see this same error on the Little Free Library [map](https://littlefreelibrary.org/ourmap/), but only when using Firefox (Chrome works fine).  It seems likely that it's due to Firefox not sending the HTTP Referrer header when submitting the form data.  You can try [changing the setting](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.http.sendRefererHeader).

The defaults in FF have changed since the question was posted so it may become more prevalent now.